# java.net.URISyntaxException

Tags: java, xml, exception

I have get this exception. but this exception is not reproduced again. I want to get the cause of this

```
Exception Caught while Checking tag in XMLjava.net.URISyntaxException:
Illegal character in opaque part at index 2:
C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\.SF\config\sd.xml
stacktrace net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException.
```

Why this exception occured. How to deal with so it will not reproduce.

Comment: tried escaping the `\\`?

Answer (score 61):

A valid URI does not contain backslashes, and if it contains a `:` then the characters before the first `:` must be a "protocol".

Basically `"C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\.SF\config\sd.xml"` is a pathname, and not a valid URI.

If you want to turn a pathname into a "file:" URI, then do the following:

```
File f = new File("C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\.SF\config\sd.xml");
URI u = f.toURI();
```

This is the simplest, and most reliable and portable way to turn a pathname into a valid URI in Java.  It should work on Windows, Mac, Linux and any other platform that supports Java.  (Other solutions that involve using string bashing on a pathname are not portable.)

But you need to realize that "file:" URIs have a number of caveats, as described in the javadocs for the [`File.toURI()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toURI()) method.  For example, a "file:" URI created on one machine usually denotes a different resource (or no resource at all) on another machine.

Comment: it doesn't like spaces as well and it has to be / instead of \\ or `\\ or //

Answer (score 12):

The root cause for this is file path contains the forward slashes instead of backward slashes in windows.

Try like this to resolve the problem:

```
"file:" + string.replace("\\", "/");
```

Comment: There is a better way: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2856542/139985

Answer (score 8):

You must have the string like so:

```
String windowsPath = file:/C:/Users/sizu/myFile.txt;
URI uri = new URI(windowsPath);
File file = new File(uri);
```

Usually, people do something like this:

```
String windowsPath = file:C:/Users/sizu/myFile.txt;
URI uri = new URI(windowsPath);
File file = new File(uri);
```

or something like this:

```
String windowsPath = file:C:\Users\sizu\myFile.txt;
URI uri = new URI(windowsPath);
File file = new File(uri);
```

Comment: For me on Windows 8 the "file:C:\" approach did not work but "file:C:/" was working. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

It needs a complete uri with type/protocol
e.g

```
file:/C:/Users/Sumit/Desktop/s%20folder/SAMPLETEXT.txt


File file = new File("C:/Users/Sumit/Desktop/s folder/SAMPLETEXT.txt");
file.toURI();//This will return the same string for you.
```

I will rather use direct string to avoid creating extra file object.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same "opaque" error while passing a URI on the command line to a script. This was on windows. I had to use forward slashes, NOT backslashes. This resolved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't like spaces as well and it has to be / instead of \ or `\ or //

zipFilePath = "C:/test/v";