# using relative paths for embedded neo4j in spring-boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, neo4j, uri, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to setup the sample spring-boot-neo4j application but with an embedded database. I added required dependencies and configurations as suggested [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-nosql.html#boot-features-connecting-to-neo4j-embedded) and [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/4.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#_configuring_the_embedded_driver). While this works for absolute paths

```
spring.data.neo4j.uri=file://var/tmp/graph.db
```

I cant seem to find a way to specify relative paths. I tried `file://graph.db` and  `file://./graph.db` and `file://~/graph.db` but get this

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.driver.EmbeddedDriver.createPermanentFileStore(EmbeddedDriver.java:211) ~[neo4j-ogm-embedded-driver-2.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.driver.EmbeddedDriver.configure(EmbeddedDriver.java:102) ~[neo4j-ogm-embedded-driver-2.0.5.jar:na]
```

tried dropping `file://` and used `graph.db` or `./graph.db` but get `URI is not absolute`

tried `file:./graph.db` but get `URI is not hierarchical`

I want to use path relative to project location (or home folder) can somebody point how to specify such paths. I am using neo4j-ogm 2.0.5, gradle 2.14, spring-boot 1.4.2 and jdk 1.8.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Behold mighty cross-platform solution:

```
  @Value("${spring.data.neo4j.uri:default}")
  private String neoUri;

  @Bean
  public Configuration neoConfig() throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
    String path = neoUri;
    Configuration.Builder builder = new Configuration.Builder();
    if (!"default".equals(path)) {
      LOG.info("Configured database uri: " + path);
      path = path.replace('\\', '/');
      URI uri = new URI(path);
      if ("file".equals(uri.getScheme())) {
        File file = new File(uri.getSchemeSpecificPart());
        path = "file:///" + file.getCanonicalFile().getAbsolutePath().replace('\\', '/');
        LOG.info("Absolute database path: " + path);
      }
      builder.uri(path);
    }
    // TODO: process other neo4j properties
    return builder.build();
  }
```

Limitations: can't use backslash as part of directory name ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ${user.dir} to resolve a absolut path.

```
uri=file:${user.dir}/target/mock_data/neo4j_${random.uuid}/graph.db
uri=file:${user.dir}/../neo4j_${random.uuid}/graph.db
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not work (at least not in windows) -- `java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 7: file:D:\src\neo4j-loader\graph.db` . I tried `file:/` and `file://`, different error message but no luck. The `:` char seems to be the issue. will try in linux

Comment: This works only on linux! Post a cross-platform solution.

Comment: replace `${user.dir}` with `#{T(java.lang.System).getProperty('user.dir').replace('\\','/')}` I think you need to develop your own Windows solution with [SpEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-methods). Because Windows has its own way to tread paths and "fancy characters" like back slash, white spaces, ... [See details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856126/java-net-urisyntaxexception). Also note the @Bean solution that digx1 mentions. You can do amazing things with SpEL but it can be easier to write plain Java code.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment and as Thomas correctly mentioned, you cannot use relative paths with the embedded datastore and the OGM.

You could:

- Use an environment variable (as Thomas mentions).  See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html) for the various options on how to pass this in.
- Specify a `@Bean` of type `org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration` and set the URI by calling something like `Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toString();` to get the current directory and then append the relative directory you want.