# Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1, Flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter, gradle, build.gradle

- Where:
  Build file '/home/dhiraj/Desktop/mine/hamrokart-flutter/android/app/build.gradle' line: 55
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: C:\Users\nibba\key.jks

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.net.URISyntaxException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856126/java-net-urisyntaxexception). You're running on a Unix-like system with `/` paths but that's a Windows path with `\`. Also seems to be someone else's "Java Key Store" file for signing the app.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your DNS Resolver config file is writable:

Open Terminal.

Type : `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`

Change the IP address in the file to: **8.8.8.8**

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to save the file.

Now you run flutter.

(OR)

delete `.grade` folder

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Before you paste this in even more locations, please take the time to read [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions).