# Illegal character error after migration to spring 5

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, migration

I am working on some legacy code. It has run under Spring (spring boot starter parent 0.5.0.M7) and Java 1.7, but the time has come to migrate. I decided to migrate to Spring 5 (spring boot starter parent 2.4.5) and Java 1.8. I have refactored to the point that the code compiles without errors or warnings, but when I try to run the code I get:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 11: jar:file:<my jarfile path redacted>!/
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.ExecutableArchiveLauncher.<init>(ExecutableArchiveLauncher.java:41)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.<init>(JarLauncher.java:30)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:45)
    ... 6 more
```

I have looked at the Procfile (which I didn't change in the migration) and the path there seems correct. The program is a web application which I try to run using the same command I did previously:

```
java -jar target/<my jar file name> --server.port=8020
```

I am unclear on how to track down the error.
I am running under windows 10 (both pre-migration and post-migration).
The code is built using maven. Running mvn --version returns 3.5.0.

My pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.conservationcenter</groupId>
<artifactId><redacted></artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>0.1</version>
<name><redacted></name>

<properties>
    <spring.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.0.1.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
      <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.4</version> 
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId></dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId></dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.radiadesign.catalina.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>redis</artifactId>
        <version>0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- file upload -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sendgrid</groupId>
        <artifactId>sendgrid-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20080701</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- DB/ORM -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Utilities-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>15.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <!--Migrations-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.flyway</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
  <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
  <version>1.3</version>
  <scope>test</scope></dependency>

<dependency>
       <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
       <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
       <version>1.9.5</version>
       <scope>test</scope></dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.fluentlenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>fluentlenium-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.01</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>local-lib</id>
        <name>Local Lib Repository</name>
        <url>file://${basedir}/lib</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>spring-central</id>
        <name>repo</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/repo</url>
    </pluginRepository>

    <pluginRepository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Maven Plugin Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>


<build>
    <finalName>crc-water</finalName>

    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.searls</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasmine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <preloadSources>
                    <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/resources/javascripts/vendor/jquery-1.10.1.min.js
                    </source>
                    <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/resources/javascripts/vendor/angular.min.js</source>
                    <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/resources/javascripts/vendor/angular-route.min.js
                    </source>
                    <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/resources/javascripts/vendor/underscore-min.js
                    </source>
                    <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/resources/javascripts/vendor/angular-mocks.js
                    </source>
                    <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/resources/javascripts/vendor/moment.js
                    </source>
                </preloadSources>
                <jsSrcDir>src/main/webapp/resources/javascripts</jsSrcDir>
                <jsTestSrcDir>src/test/webapp/resources/javascripts</jsTestSrcDir>
                <specIncludes>
                    <include>*Spec.js</include>
                </specIncludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                </includes>
                <environmentVariables>
                    <DATABASE_URL>postgresql://<user redacted>:<password redacted>@localhost:5433/<redacted></DATABASE_URL>
                </environmentVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.flyway</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/<redacted></url>
                <user><redacted></user>
                <password><redacted></password>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: What character is at index `11` (the redacted part)? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856126/java-net-urisyntaxexception).

Comment: Remove `spring.version` and `hibernate.version` those are ancient versions and don't work with Spring BOot 2.4.3. Also remove the `org.springframework` dependencies and `org.hibernate` dependencies. There is probably more wrong with your dependencies (conflicting versions, duplicaties with wrong versions etc.). Also remove the `version` from the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`.

Comment: Kayaman an 'a'.

Comment: Deinum - how do those suggestions play a role in the question? I have no doubt there are probably issues with things in the pom, and probably incompatibilities, but can you be specific about how those impact the specific error? Also, I tried the things you suggested and end up with some basic things not being defined (like @column).

Comment: I ended up reworking the pom altogether (per M.Deinum Mar suggestion). I am still baffled about why the error occurred, but I have moved on with a more current pom setup